# Why does Vaadin require a license in the Docker build?

Tags: vaadin

I am using Vaadin 23.5.5 for a private project without using the Pro components of Vaadin. When I build the project in a Docker container, Vaadin aborts the build and asks for a license key file.

```
...
Running Vite ...
Opening the system browser to validate the license. If the browser is not open, please open https://vaadin.com/pro/validate-license?connect=UUID&productName=vaadin-board&productVersion=23.3.5 manually.
If you are working offline, please visit https://vaadin.com/pro/validate-license?getOfflineKey=ABC for an offline license.
...
```

This are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter'
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-storage'
    implementation 'com.vaadin:vaadin-spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-data-firestore'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
   
    implementation 'de.jfancy:star-rating:1.0.3'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "com.vaadin:vaadin-bom:${vaadinVersion}"
        mavenBom "com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies:${springCloudGcpVersion}"
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}
```

The entire dependency tree:

https://gist.github.com/benocms/1d08207e5a89f6d50965a5136938a8a8

My understanding is that the use of the Core components is free. Am I wrong about this? Or is this a bug?

Comment: Please verify that you are only using  free components and DON'T have vaadin as dependency. Free components come from vaadin-core.

Comment: As far as I know, yes. Please see my update above.

Comment: I'm no Gradle expert, but there should be a way to find out which Dependency includes the wrong dependency

Comment: @Ben Run `gradle dependencies` to get a dependency tree. Or `./gradlew moduleName:dependencies` if using Gradle Wrapper. Please inspect it yourself to see if any paid components are being used and if you can't find one, add the output to your post and we will look!

Comment: I added the entire dependency tree in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed now.

The main cause was caused by the 'de.jfancy:star-rating' dependency. This library implements the 'grid-pro-flow' module, which requires a Pro license.

```
'de.jfancy:star-rating:1.0.3'
|    \--- com.vaadin:vaadin:23.0.1 -> 23.3.6
|         +--- com.vaadin:vaadin-core:23.3.6 (*)
|         +--- com.vaadin:vaadin-board-flow:23.3.6
|         +--- com.vaadin:vaadin-charts-flow:23.3.6
|         +--- com.vaadin:vaadin-cookie-consent-flow:23.3.6
|         +--- com.vaadin:vaadin-crud-flow:23.3.6
|         |    +--- com.vaadin:vaadin-text-field-flow:23.3.6 (*)
|         |    +--- com.vaadin:vaadin-grid-flow:23.3.6 (*)
|         |    +--- com.vaadin:vaadin-button-flow:23.3.6 (*)
|         |    \--- com.vaadin:vaadin-renderer-flow:23.3.6
|         +--- com.vaadin:vaadin-grid-pro-flow:23.3.6
|         |    \--- com.vaadin:vaadin-grid-flow:23.3.6 (*)
|         +--- com.vaadin:vaadin-map-flow:23.3.6
|         |    \--- com.vaadin:flow-server:23.3.4 (*)
|         +--- com.vaadin:vaadin-rich-text-editor-flow:23.3.6
|         \--- com.vaadin:collaboration-engine:5.3.0
|              +--- com.vaadin:vaadin-avatar-flow:23.3.0 -> 23.3.6 (*)
|              +--- com.vaadin:vaadin-messages-flow:23.3.0 -> 23.3.6 (*)
|              +--- com.vaadin:vaadin-field-highlighter-flow:23.3.0 -> 23.3.6
|              +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.14.1 -> 2.13.4.2 (*)
|              +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.14.1 -> 2.13.4 (*)
|              \--- com.vaadin:license-checker:1.5.1 -> 1.11.2 (*)
```