# vaadin 24.0.0.alpha8 PreRelease build error on azure agent

Tags: vaadin

We have recently tried to do an experimental upgrade to vaadin 24 PreRelease version. We were able to build and run the application in local environment but the application fails to build on azure agent with below error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:24.0.0.alpha8:build-frontend (default) on project rmod-tools: Execution default of goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:24.0.0.alpha8:build-frontend failed: Unable to validate the license, please check your internet connection. If you need to work offline then please go to https://vaadin.com/pro/validate-license?getOfflineKey=mid-abfe707e-8d41af4e to retrieve an offline key. For troubleshooting steps, see https://vaadin.com/licensing-faq-and-troubleshooting.

The application builds successfully in local env.

Comment: Maybe related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75352660/why-does-vaadin-require-a-license-in-the-docker-build ; What versions did you update from? Do you use Commercial/Pro features? Have you tried the suggested things in the error message?

Comment: we are upgrading from vaadin 23 to 24 pre-release version and we are not using any pro/commercial components.